# Is there a c++ fcgi process manager?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

Nginx is my WEB Server,and there is a TCP Server used for processing data.I want to use fcgi process to communicate with TCP Server,the fcgi process is code in C++.I need a process manager between WEB Server and C++ fcgi.

Actually,I found a C++ fcgi process manager ---- "spawn_fcgi".But in my case,it always lost connections in stress test(maybe the problem came from the C++ fastcgi++2.1，a third party library，but I'm not sure).

Now, I want to change some part to locate problem,but I only find "spawn_fcgi",is there another C++ fcgi process manager?

Anyway,apologize for my bad English and thanks in advance.